# WKWebViewDataStore leaking

Tags: macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I'm using multiple instances of `WKWebView` in my document-based application, as preview windows and to display some data etc.

The views are set to nil when documents are closed, I'm removing their `messageHandler` instances and everything works fine, but Instruments and Xcode keep complaining that multiple instances of `WKWebViewDataStore` get leaked.

[image: WKWebSiteDataStore leak notification in Xcode]

It's impossible to null the datastore, and I don't use it at all anyway. I have no idea how it gets leaked, or if it's just a bug in `WKWebView`. Where should I start debugging the problem?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I'm pretty sure this is a `WKWebView` bug, because it happens in an empty project, too.